# How to nudge an element by 1px from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below I need to nudge `ins` by `1px` from right to left
But it is moved by `12px` in one step
What is wrong ?
The starting position should be - absolute - in the horizontal center of parent

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
var ins = $('#ins');
let x = ins.position().left - 1;
console.log(x);
ins.css('left', x + 'px');
});
```

```css
.wrap{background:lightblue; display:inline-block; width:50%; position:relative; height:54px;}
.ins{background:orange; position:absolute; width:25px; height:25px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='ins' id='ins'></div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ins.position().left` has included the negative X translation as well which explain the 12px difference (.ins has a width of 25px)

To achieve 1px nudge, use `ins.css('left')` instead to get the css `left` value as string (e.g. 170px). Then parse it as integer before minus one `parseInt(ins.css('left'), 10) - 1;` (e.g. 170 - 1)

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
var ins = $('#ins');
let x = parseInt(ins.css('left'), 10) - 1;
console.log(x);
ins.css('left', x + 'px');
});
```

```css
.wrap{background:lightblue; display:inline-block; width:50%; position:relative; height:54px;}
.ins{background:orange; position:absolute; width:25px; height:25px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='ins' id='ins'></div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: what is `10`, pls ?

Comment: The `10` here refers to the decimal system. 

The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [CSS Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to get this done.

Don't forget to use `left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;` to put the orange square at the center of the blue rectangle.

```js
let position = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var ins = $('#ins');
  position.x -= 1;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(position));
  ins.css('transform', `translate(${position.x}px,${position.y}px`);
});
```

```css
.wrap{background:lightblue; display:inline-block; width:50%; position:relative; height:54px;}
.ins{background:orange; position:absolute; width:25px; height:25px; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='ins' id='ins'></div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```